# Pass-Through parameters in recursive code

Tags: recursion, parameters

When writing large amounts of recursive code (for valid reasons), I have come across many parameters that are not used in specific functions, but are still needed for a subset of all of the functions.
IE this situation (a, b & c are numbers):

```
function fun1(a, b, c) {
    if(a > b) {
        return fun2(a, b, c);
    } else if(b > c) {
        return fun3(a, b, c);
    } else {
        return a;
    }
}

function fun2(a, b, c) {
    return fun1(a + b, a - b, c);
}

function fun3(a, b, c) {
    return fun1(a * c, b, a / c);
}
```

(I don't actually know if this terminates)

In this example, `fun2` never actually uses `c`, but it still has to require `c` as a parameter. In `fun3`, this is the same thing but for `b`, and `fun1` only cares about `a`.

In this situation, what should be done to reduce the number of parameters down to only the parameters each function needs & not the parameters that get used in other functions?

(When I say `not used`, I mean passed through)

Answer (score 4):

You're contradicting yourself:

**1**

> `fun2` never actually uses `c`

**2**

```
function fun2(a, b, c) {
    return fun1(a + b, a - b, c);
}
```

Passing a parameter counts as using it. You're thinking that it's unused because it just happens to call `fun1`, at a time when `fun1` also happens to be the method which called `fun2` in the first place.

But that's not inherently the case.

- `fun2` could be using `ADifferentMethod(c)` internally
- `fun2` could be called by `AnotherCompletelyDifferentMethod()`

In either of those cases, your assumption that `c` is "not used" does not stick.

In this recursive structure, the parent `fun1` and the child `fun1` should not be labeled as "the same function". They are not. They each have their own separate execution with their own separate scope.

Just like how two separate objects of the same class type are not labeled as "the same object"; **two method calls of the same method are not labeled as "the same method"** (not in this sense you're trying to use, at least).

Comment: I mean it `fun2` never uses `c` in a sense that it just gets passed through. The functions I have have ~7 parameters, and 4 of them usually just gets passed through. I am wondering what I should do about that & is there any way to get rid of those 4 pass-through parameters

Comment: @MrYurihiredstone: You can't, because of what I concluded the answer with: _two method calls of the same method are not labeled as "the same method" (in the sense of their variable scope)_. When you drill down deeper into the call stack, you always have to pass your parameters along. Regardless of whether this is recursion or a deep stack of unique methods.

Comment: Right. That is what I was thinking. I really don't want to have to have 7 parameters on each method because that is far too many. But I guess I will have to work with it

Comment: @MrYurihiredstone: If you're simply looking to shorten the code, how about making a DTO class that holds the needed data, and pass a single instance of that down the call stack? The methods remain functionally equivalent but the signature is shortened.

Comment: On what basis do you conclude that seven parameters is too many? If you need seven, then that's how many you have to have.

Comment: I doubt your answer is useful to OP as is. You are only pointing at OP mistakes in explaining his problem. OP used code as example of a more bloated situation. If you want to challenge premises, you should probably comment instead. @David Arno I understand he believes he need to refactor because he is leaving most arguments unmodified.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek: The question as it is currently is asked is defeated due to the incorrect premise that a parameter is only relevant when it is used directly in a method body and not in an underlying method. OP's actual question (`what should be done to reduce the number of parameters down to only the parameters each function needs [..]?`) is therefore null and void - there is no justifiable basis to exclude these parameters. This is not a general "how do I pass less parameters?" question, it's asking how to remove allegedly irrelevant parameters (and they are in fact not irrelevant)

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek `because he is leaving most arguments unmodified` The relevance of a parameter is not defined by whether it is modified or not. The relevance of a parameter is defined by whether it is needed for the method body (i.e. when the absence of the parameter leads to the inability to perform the needed responsibilities). Whether a parameter is needed or not inherently also includes _method bodies of underlying methods_ (and it is these underlying methods that OP is wrongly excluding from his assessment of the relevance of the parameters).

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek OP's suggestion, that you can only pass parameters when they are are immediately handled, effectively implies that you can never create an intermediary layer without also altering the passed data. And when you don't need a conversion (e.g. to pass a string value from the UI all the way to the database), why would you pointlessly alter this value every step of the way? It's futile work with no merit.

Comment: @Flater You certainly don't need a function of 10 arguments to change one field of a 10 column database row. We are on software engineering. I hope we can do better than this and it's exactly what OP question is about.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek: Well then those additional parameters are **not needed** and can certainly be omitted. But that's besides the point, OP's `c` parameter is actually **needed** for the underlying `fun1` method that is called from inside the `fun2` method body, hence why it can't be omitted from the `fun2` parameters.

Comment: @Flater You stick to what code actually is but miss what's the biggest picture in OP situation. Suppose you have a DFS and you calculate several things on it. Each time you add more things to calculate, to the point you have 10 parameters that are filled and need recursively to be passed. Do you need 10 parameters for calculating a DFS ? **No**. Are they used ? Yes. This is code smell and OP states he is in this situation *only a subset of functions care*, I understand the parameters are here for pure context value. He needs refactoring. I don't know, check my proposal

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek: OP provided a generalized example. It is impossible to divinate the intention of the code, the posted code is completely context-free. You're responding about a possible use case that you've thought of, with no confirmation from OP that your assumptions in any way hold true. OP asked a generalized question, and therefore receives a generalized answer.

Comment: I prefer hypothetically useful to certainly not. I have no intention to discuss further my initial judgement.

Answer (score 1):

The common scenario for improving number of parameters is to abstract a portion of them inside a class or structure that makes sense.

For example, we could imagine `a`, `b`, and `c` in a class in your example, and have the following methods (python code):

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def fun1(self):
        if(self.a > self.b)
            return self.fun2()
        elif(self.b > self.c)
            return self.fun3()
        return self.a

    def fun2(self):
        self.a = self.a + self.b
        self.b = self.a - self.b
        return self.fun1()

    def fun3(self):
        self.a = self.a * self.c
        self.c = self.a / self.c
        return self.fun1()
```

The methods in themselves can use the object instance to set and pass the arguments. There is in this pattern no need to pass unmodified arguments.

Comment: I would only do this if it really makes sense to group the arguments together like that. If not, it might only further complicate things, as I would argue here. (Also as a small nitpick, your implementation does not actually match the OP's.)